# Should reputation be reset for migrated question?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

I recently posted a topic that did not belong on the site. The question was migrated to a more appropriate site. In the meantime however the question was down voted on this site. After migration, the effect of the negative votes remain on this site. On the new site, the question is being answered so I do not want to delete it.

Is there anything wrong with this process? It seems a bit odd that I retain negative reputation for a question that I cannot delete on this site. The migrated question only exists on the new site, while the negative reputation from that question only exists on this site. I hope this is clear, please advise if it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copy of [your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80639/what-is-a-good-method-to-clean-stainless-steel-hot-water-pot) here on Home Improvement will be automatically deleted after 30 days (source: [Delete old migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/delete-old-migrated-questions)), at which time you'll get those reputation points back.

The most highly upvoted feature request to change that behavior, [Reset votes on migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions), has been declined, so the answer is to be patient, I'm afraid.